# how store array with a function and print arrays in other function in php

Tags: php, arrays

i want to store data as array with function like "add_to_head"
than use it these array that stores in "$add_to_head" varible in other function like "load_head" in php langueade.
i coded this but this return two errors and not work correctly,

my code :

```html
function add_to_head($src,$type){
    $add_to_head = array() ;
    switch ($type) {
        case "css":
            $add_to_head[] = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$src.'" type="text/css" />';
            break;
        case "js":
            $add_to_head[] = '<script src="'.$src.'" type="text/javascript"></script>';
            break;
        default:
            $add_to_head[] = $src;
    }
    global $add_to_head;
}



//function to run add_to_footer or add_to_head in your theme
function load_head(){
    foreach ($add_to_head as $item){
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: dnt use global instead of that return the array

Comment: @ArunKumaresh I got two erors Notice: Undefined variable: add_to_head 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Where  are you calling this add_to_head function? It seems to accept two mandatory arguments src and type. How are you supposed to pass these two parameters??

Comment: call the function add_to_head() and pass two paramater $src and $type to it

Comment: @ArunKumaresh i called every both function and get eror,

add_to_head('test.css', 'css');
add_to_head('3.css', 'css');
load_head();

Comment: @ObjectManipulator i called this in sample page with these functions, and passed two parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in this way:

```
<?php

function add_to_head($values){
    $add_to_head = array() ;
    foreach($values as $value){ 
        switch ($value['type']) {
            case "css":
                $add_to_head[] = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$value['src'].'" type="text/css" />';
                break;
            case "js":
                $add_to_head[] = '<script src="'.$value['src'].'" type="text/javascript"></script>';
                break;
            default:
                $add_to_head[] = $value['src'];
        }  
    }    
    return $add_to_head;
}



//function to run add_to_footer or add_to_head in your theme
function load_head($add_to_head){ 
    foreach ($add_to_head as $item){ 
        echo '<textarea>'.$item.'</textarea>';
    }
}
// hold the return array 
$values = array(
    0 => array('src'=>'test.css', 'type'=>'css'),
    1 => array('src'=>'abc.css', 'type'=>'js'),
);
$add_to_head = add_to_head($values); 

// pass here returned array
load_head($add_to_head);
```

Comment: thanks, this work but if i want add two or more to array what i must do?in this way function reteurn just ine array test it

$add_to_head = add_to_head('test.css', 'css');
$add_to_head = add_to_head('3.css', 'css');
load_head($add_to_head);

Comment: why don't you pass multiple values in an array?

Comment: can explain with a example?